# Django Rest Framework Update or Create if not exists

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-datastore

I want to use the perform an *update or create* in `django-rest-framework`, by passing **or not** the `id` field. I've got this model

```
class Etiqueta(models.Model):
    name_tag = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    description_tag = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_tag
```

And in `django-rest-framework` I've got this serializer

```
from myapp.modulos.estado_1.models import Etiqueta
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets

# Serializers define the API representation.
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Etiqueta
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name_tag',
            'description_tag'
        )

# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class TagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Etiqueta.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
```

Normally when I create an object, I perform a `POST` to the URL without the `/:id`, but if I've got an object with a **local id**, I want him to be created in the `REST` with the same id (remote id), `django` overwrite my local id and creates a new one. **Does anybody know how achieve this?** Also it is important to mention that I'm working with `google-app-engine`, `google-cloud-datastore` and `django-dbindexer`.

Answer (score 7):

This code should work for your case -

```
class TagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset = Etiqueta.objects.all()
      serializer_class = TagSerializer

      def get_object(self):
          if self.request.method == 'PUT':
              obj, created = Etiquetta.objects.get_or_create(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
              return obj
          else:
              return super(TagViewSet, self).get_object()
```

Comment: Like this first Example? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: Similarly, but you might bit need to override that many methods.

Comment: It looks beautiful, but it looks like the `request` object it is not reachable from that scope. The `get_object` method is called with only one argument.

Comment: It seems that in my case (environment), the `django-indexer` or the `google-app-engine` does not allow to achieve this: I've got `DatabaseError: invalid filter: __key__ filter value must be a Key; received None (a NoneType).` I've try defining `id` column in the model, or even defining the `__key__` method, but i'm stuck there. :(

Comment: R u using relational database or mongo etc.

Comment: Unless I am wrong , ModelViewSet assumes relational database backend. Infact I had to use a package called restframework-mongoengine to get it work for mongo

Comment: I had 3 issues with the previous version, first `self.kwargs.get('id')` was returning None (The URL was `.../:id`). Then, the `get_or_create` is a `django` method, not a `django-nonrel` method, so the deserialization process was not working (dont know why really). And finally, the `get_or_create` needed all the columns of the object, so I pass it directly from the `request`. Maybe you can understand what was really going on... But that is working on `Google App Engine` with `django-nonrel` and `dbindexer` right now. Thank you very much, without you I wouldn't be able to have this feature.

Comment: This is **not** a solution because you are creating the model before serializer errors can be thrown which can also create security holes!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at how Django REST framework does currently and adapts your create method to update whenever you have an id field.

The original `ViewSet.create` is [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/73feaf6299827607eab94ce96b77b73671880626/rest_framework/mixins.py#L17) and the `ViewSet.update` is [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/73feaf6299827607eab94ce96b77b73671880626/rest_framework/mixins.py#L64).

Please note that you will probably end up with two different serializers for `/tag/` and `/tag/:id` since the later should not allow the `id` field to be writable while the former should.

Answer (score 0):

I've write [a drf views mixin](https://gist.github.com/wonderbeyond/844ae9a7b252ef18c470136e84ccfe6b) for updating an object by id, if no corresponding object, just create it then update.